# Arranging Rows of a Dataframe by the Values in Another Vector

Tags: r, dataframe

To preface, I have read some posts which *sort* rows of a dataframe by the values in another vector, but this isn't quite what I'm after.
My data contains patient ID's and that patient's data on that row:

```
           ID Group    L_HCH    R_HCH    L_HCB    R_HCB    L_HCT    R_HCT L_HC_Total R_HC_Total
121    GP_M01   PAT 0.120000 0.110000 0.040000 0.040000 0.040000 0.040000   0.200000   0.190000
122    GP_M02   PAT 0.110000 0.120000 0.060000 0.060000 0.020000 0.010000   0.190000   0.190000
123    GP_M03   PAT 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
124    GP_M05   PAT 0.117340 0.125620 0.050664 0.045523 0.020289 0.012440   0.188293   0.183583
125    GP_M08   PAT 0.114000 0.119000 0.049000 0.065000 0.027000 0.011000   0.190000   0.195000
126  GSTTC_01   PAT 0.151000 0.140000 0.049000 0.058000 0.042000 0.033000   0.242000   0.231000
127  GSTTC_11   PAT 0.130000 0.130000 0.080000 0.070000 0.030000 0.040000   0.240000   0.240000
```

etc.
Some of the rows are in the wrong place. I have another list of *only* the ID's in a known good order:

```
> PT_IDs
[1] "CON_L01"   "CON_L03"   "CON_L04"   "CON_L05"   "CON_L07"   "CON_L10"   "CON_L14"   "CON_L16"   "CON_L17"   "CON_L18"  
 [11] "CON_L19"   "CON_L23"   "CON_L25"   "CON_L26"   "CON_L27"   "CON_L29"   "CON_L30"   "CON_L31"   "CON_L35"   "CON_L36"
```

etc.

I *could*, I suppose, write the main dataframe out to a `csv`, rearrange the rows manually, and then read it back in, but I would like to know what the best way is to rearrange the rows of the dataframe by the `ID` column so that they are in the same order as the equivalent IDs in the `PT_IDs` list. All of the values that are in the `PT_IDs` list are also in the `ID` column, so there is no funny business there.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Try `df %>% arrange(factor(ID, levels = pd_ids))` You can can look at Ronak's answer in above link

Comment: Thank you both for the responses - Ronak's solution there using `arrange()` does seem to be the cleanest and most readable. I might swap out my solution using `match()` for this in future.

Answer (score 0):

After a more thorough scoot through the `R` documentation, I came across the `match()` function, which seemed to have the functionality I wanted ([match][1]) - for anybody else who runs into this, the solution boiled down to:

```
df_arranged <- patient_df[match(PT_IDs, patient_df$ID), ]
```

Match just returns the position of a given element, so that is used to index the correct rows. Hopefully I'm not just adding to a pile of duplicate questions!
[1]: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/match